# Read multiple images from input and turn them into base64 string

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I had a lot of frustration with this problem so I'm here to share the solution

Comment: Where is the solution that you wanted to share?

Comment: please ask a question above and then add the solution into an answer below when your question gets reopened

Comment: I added the solution below in the answers but I deleted it accidentally, now it's added back.

Answer (score 1):

This example is in React but you can easily modify it to standard javascript.

If it's standard javascript just change `const [images, setImages] = useState([]);` into `let images = []`.

```js
const [images, setImages] = useState([]);

const formatImage = async() => {
  try {
    for (let i = 0; i < e.target.files.length; i++) {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[i]);
      reader.onload = (readerEvent) => {
        images.push(readerEvent.target ? .result);
      };
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

```html
<input type="file" multiple onChange={formatImage} />
```

And here is an example of putting these images on Firebase Firestore and again if it's standard javascript change `setImages([])` to `images = []`

```js
const addImage = async() => {
  try {
    Promise.all(
      images.map(
        async(file: any) =>
        await addDoc(collection(db, "images"), {
          image: file,
          date: Timestamp.now(),
        })
      )
    );

    setImages([]);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```